# Show that a $\pi$-system that is also a $d$-system is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory

How to show that a $\pi$-system that is also a $d$-system is a $\sigma$-algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote a collection of of subsets of a set $E$ that is both a $\pi$-system and a $d$-system.  By definition of $\pi$-system, $\varnothing \in \mathcal{A}$.  By definition of $d$-system, $E\in \mathcal{A}$.

If $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then $E\backslash A\equiv A^{c}\in \mathcal{A}$ because $\mathcal{A}$ is a $d$-system.  Thus, $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under complements.  Because $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under complements and closed under finite intersections, the inequality $(A^{c}\cap B^{c})^{c}=A\cup B$ shows that $\mathcal{A}$ is also closed under finite unions (i.e., if $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$, then $A\cup B \in \mathcal{A}$). $\mathcal{A}$ is a set algebra.

To show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, all that remains is to show that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under countable unions.  Let $(A_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ denote an arbitrary sequence of subsets of $E$ such that $A_{n}\in \mathcal{A}$ for all $n$.  Well, we can define $B_{k}\equiv \cup_{n=1}^{k}A_{n}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.  Clearly, $(B_{k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an increasing sequence, and $B_{k}\in \mathcal{A}$ for all $k$ because $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under finite unions.  Hence, $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}=\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}B_{k}\in \mathcal{A}$.